# Adding extra operations to the mouseReleaseEvent

Tags: python, pyqt4, qgraphicsitem

For QGraphicsItem (I have a class subclass of this QGraphicsItem), there is in-built mouseReleaseEvent method and that is private. As of now, this is used in making the Graphic Item to pan and to update the position(Built in feature). I want to add additional features, like printing the position where it is released and some other statements. How should I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see, `QGraphicsItem.mouseReleaseEvent()` can be over-ridden in the usual manor (I've forgotten a lot of c++ terminology, but as far as I can see from the documentation, the method is not actually private, just protected)

```
class MyQGraphicsItem(QGraphicsItem):
    ....

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        # your code here

        # call the base class implementation if you want the standard behaviour to still happen
        return QGraphicsItem.mouseReleaseEvent(self, event)
```

Comment: I was trying with eventFilters (if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseMove:), until I get to know, the use of return statement mentioned in your answer .. awesome... missed simple thing.